# Why my gradient is not gradient perpendicular to contour lines?

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra

I got confused with a very simple problem.

Suppose we have a function $f(x_1,x_2)=3x_1+5x_2$

The gradient of $f$ is $(3,5)^T$ at any point.

So, if I evaluate $f'(5,1)$, it will be $(3,5)^T$ at it is not perpendicular to contour lines. What was wrong here?

[image]

Comment: How did you get the vector shown in the figure?  (Is this what you've computed as $f'(5,1)$?

Comment: He has the arrow from $(5,1)$ that is *pointing to* $(3,5)$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A vector is not a place.  It is a motion. The vector $(3,5)$ is not an arrow that ends at the place with coordinates $(3,5)$. It is an arrow that starts  somewhere and moves 3 units to the right and 5 units up.  If you draw it starting at $(5,1)$, it will end at $(5+3,1+5) = (8,6)$, and if you draw it this way you will see that it is perpendicular to the contour line.

The arrow you drew starts at $(3,5)$ and ends at $(5,1)$, and represents the vector $(3-5, 5-1) = (-2,4)$. It's the wrong arrow.

Comment: thanks!, but i used to draw arrows like this for quadratic functions https://www.math.uic.edu/coursepages/math210/labpages/lab5 . why in that case, it is correct? because there is a x1 and x2 in the derivatives?

Comment: It's not because of the $x_1$ and $x_2$. It's because of what I said.

Comment: you mean i got things correct because it is a coincidence with quadratic function. If it is not quadratic, I cannot just connect $(x_1,x_2)$ with $f'(x_1,x_2)$